# Binding dataframes returned by a function

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a function in R called build_dataframe(year), which accepts a year and builds the required dataframe for it.

```
build_dataframe <- function(year) {
     #build a data frame for given year
}
```

I want to build data frames for multiple years say

```
years = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003)
```

How can I do this efficiently? I tried something like

```
rbind(sapply(years, build_dataframe))
```

but corrupts the dataframes.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Did you try `lapply`

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(years, build_dataframe) )` maybe?

Comment: ^^ Thanks @thelatemail that works